# Uso de api de google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

En mi app hago uso de la api de google maps. Hago uso de la api en 2 partes de la app, en uno si funciona correctamente pero en otro no me muestra la activity, mi pregunta es la siguiente ¿Una vez este habilitada la api en la app, se puede usar en cualquier sitio y cuantas veces se deseen? Por que al lanzar el intent a otra actividad si lo hace y cuando lo lanzo a la deseada no. Lo que pasa cuando se lanza la activity deseada es que se pone la pantalla en blanco y vuelve a la activity anterior, pero no me muestra error en el logcat. Intento lanzar la actividad deseada pulsando un botón de un cardView.

Aquí dejo el código donde intento lanzar la activity, que es desde el adaptador para los cardviews:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final EventoViewHolder viewHolder, final int pos) {

    nombreMonum = items.get(pos).getNombre();
    id = items.get(pos).getId();
    lat = items.get(pos).getLatitud();
    lon = items.get(pos).getLongitud();

    viewHolder.imagen.setImageResource(asignarImg(id));
    viewHolder.nombre.setText(items.get(pos).getNombre());
    viewHolder.descripcion.setText(items.get(pos).getDescripcion());
    viewHolder.galeria.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(act, Galeria.class );
            Log.i("Datos","id "+id);
            i.putExtra("id", id);
            act.startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    viewHolder.ir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(act, MapsActivity.class );
            Log.i("Datos","nombreMonum "+ nombreMonum);
            Log.i("Datos","latitud "+lat);
            Log.i("Datos","longitud "+lon);
            i.putExtra("latitud", lat);
            i.putExtra("longitud", lon);
            i.putExtra("nombre", nombreMonum);
            act.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

y aquí donde lo recojo:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    String nombre;
    Double lat, lon;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.maps);

        nombre = getIntent().getExtras().getString("nombre");
        lat = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("latitud");
        lon = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("longitud");

        Log.i("seguimiento","nombre "+ nombre);
        Log.i("seguimiento","latitud "+lat);
        Log.i("seguimiento","longitud "+lon);
        //Localizan en el layout el id map
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        //le decimos al frasgment que lo obtenga de forma asincrona
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

        // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
        LatLng monumento = new LatLng(lat, lon);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(monumento).title(nombre).snippet("monumento"));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(monumento));
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    }

}
```

tambien dejo el código del .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    map:cameraZoom="16"
    tools:context=".Actividad.MapsActivity" />
```

Comment: android? si vas a agregar detalles, pulsa el botón editar y no agreges comentarios

Comment: ya lo he modificadp

Comment: Hola @tripossi, podrías ponernos el código que has implementado donde se lanza el intent?

Comment: ya lo he puesto aunque no se visualizarlo correctamente jeje, sorry

Comment: la api la deseas usar en un sitio o una aplicación? "Por que al lanzar el intent a otra actividad si lo hace y cuando lo lanzo a la deseada no." cual es la otra actividad que comentas.